# If I don't choose a file and press the send button, I will get a popup but it'll break any future popups

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

If I press `Send ☞` without choosing a file, it'll say "No file selected." in a little Bootstrap warning alert but it seems to break all future alerts like file uploaded or file already exists on disk.

If I make an error alert like file already on disk, it'll work and won't break future alerts (meaning it won't stop alerts that popup in the future from showing).

So, why is the "No file selected" alert breaking other alerts?

In this clip, you can see me trying to make more than one of that alert but it just doesn't want to.

[image]

Here is my ejs file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Androp</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <p>
        <h1>Androp - Send to [...] MBP</h1>
        </p>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" onclick="send()">Send ☞</button>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="fileSelector">
        </div>
        <div id="alerts"></div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <div id="spinny" class="spinner-border" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem; visibility: hidden;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        const socket = io()
        const engine = socket.io.engine
        let maxSize = 0
        let sending = false

        socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
            alert(`Disconnected from laptop! Check your internet or refresh the page.  (${reason})`, "warning")
        })

        engine.on("close", reason => {
            console.log(reason)
        })

        socket.emit("getMaxSize", (size) => {
            return maxSize = size
        })

        const alert = (message, type) => {
            const wrapper = document.createElement('div')
            wrapper.innerHTML = [
                `<div class="alert alert-${type} fade show" role="alert">`,
                `   <div>${message}</div>`,
                '</div>'
            ].join('')

            document.getElementById("alerts").append(wrapper)

            return bootstrap.Alert.getOrCreateInstance(wrapper)
        }

        function send() {
            if (sending) {
                return false
            }

            sending = true

            const file = document.getElementById("fileSelector").files[0] || false

            function close(alert) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    alert.close()
                }, 3500)
            }

            if (!file) { return close(alert("No files to upload.", "warning")) }
            if (file.size >= maxSize) { return close(alert(`File is bigger than ${Math.round(maxSize / (1024 ** 2))} MB`, "danger")) }
            document.getElementById("spinny").style.visibility = 'visible'
            socket.timeout(10000).emit("upload", file, file.name, file.size, (err, status) => {
                if(err) {
                    return close(alert("Could not contact laptop within 10s, laptop might be in sleep mode. ", "warning"))
                }
                document.getElementById("spinny").style.visibility = 'hidden'
                sending = false
                return close(alert(status.message, status.success ? "success" : "danger"))
            })
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Your title should be a concise question. If you can't formulate one perhaps your question isn't clear in general. :)

Comment: You don't need to include all those boostrap js files. I think bundle.min.js is (more than) enough.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just keep them their because it just adds extra functionality (that I have yet to discover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the flag `sending = true` when you actually plan to send after validation. I would also place `sending = false` right when callback returns, even if `err`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Androp</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <p>
      <h1>Androp - Send to [...] MBP</h1>
    </p>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" onclick="send()">Send ☞</button>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" id="fileSelector">
    </div>
    <div id="alerts"></div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <div id="spinny" class="spinner-border" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem; visibility: hidden;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.0/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-7EyYLQZgWBi67fBtVxw60/OWl1kjsfrPFcaU0pp0nAh+i8FD068QogUvg85Ewy1k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    const socket = io()
    const engine = socket.io.engine
    let maxSize = 0
    let sending = false

    socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
      alert(`Disconnected from laptop! Check your internet or refresh the page.  (${reason})`, "warning")
    })

    engine.on("close", reason => {
      console.log(reason)
    })

    socket.emit("getMaxSize", (size) => {
      return maxSize = size
    })

    const alert = (message, type) => {
      const wrapper = document.createElement('div')
      wrapper.innerHTML = [
        `<div class="alert alert-${type} fade show" role="alert">`,
        `   <div>${message}</div>`,
        '</div>'
      ].join('')

      document.getElementById("alerts").append(wrapper)

      return bootstrap.Alert.getOrCreateInstance(wrapper)
    }

    function send() {
      if (sending) {
        return false
      }


      const file = document.getElementById("fileSelector").files[0] || false

      function close(alert) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert.close()
        }, 3500)
      }


      if (!file) {
        return close(alert("No files to upload.", "warning"))
      }
      if (file.size >= maxSize) {
        return close(alert(`File is bigger than ${Math.round(maxSize / (1024 ** 2))} MB`, "danger"))
      }
      sending = true

      document.getElementById("spinny").style.visibility = 'visible'
      socket.timeout(10000).emit("upload", file, file.name, file.size, (err, status) => {
        if (err) {
          return close(alert("Could not contact laptop within 10s, laptop might be in sleep mode. ", "warning"))
        }
        document.getElementById("spinny").style.visibility = 'hidden'
        sending = false
        return close(alert(status.message, status.success ? "success" : "danger"))
      })
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
</body>

</html>
```